# C# Access to SSRS

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I 've got a small C# WinForms project  that's using MSSQL 2012 EXPRESS and SSRS 2012 Express. Got my reports running fine, but now I neeed to be able to manage them through my C# Application.

So I've made a service reference to 
http://localhost/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS/ReportService2005.asmx?wsdl

but am constantly receiving 
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.

Anyone got a running sample to share that will access the service.

my code;

```
ReportService.ReportingService2005SoapClient rs = new ReportService.ReportingService2005SoapClient();
rs.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
rs.ListChildren("/", true, out items);
```

List Children throws the exception, while my app is running as Administrator.

Duncan